# Understanding website and api urls?

Tags: url, web

I have noticed that many sites have URLs that are generated and interperable. For example there is the google search one bellow:

https://www.google.com/search?q=example+search&oq=example+search&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i60j0l3.2087j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

This type of pattern seems consistent accross many different web services. What is the best practice for choosing urls and how could I learn more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question you are referring to the key value pairs separated by ampersands, right?

This is called a GET request, which is giving information to the server through the URL. The format is `website.com/path/to/page?variable1=value1&variable2=value2 etc.`

The question mark indicates the beginning of the key value pair section.

POST requests serve a similar purpose, but are not sent in the URL, so they can contain more data.

Try looking here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

This format is standard, but not essential. One could make their server interpret URLs in any way they want; however, HTML forms will automatically generate this format. This page has more info, some of which is relevant to your question: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp.